# tastypie POST method return an dict key is error but empty value

Tags: python, django, post, tastypie

I have a question about django tastypie, i want to POST data to the api,
but it return 400, and the error message is empty
  My Resource is non-orm, so i override the obj_create method
  but the GET method work well.
  Here is my code

```
class DitcObject(object):

    def __init__(self, initial=None):
        self.__dict__['_data'] = {}

        if hasattr(initial, 'items'):
            self.__dict__['_data'] = initial

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self._data.get(item, None)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__['_data'][key] = value

    def to_dict(self):
        return self._data

class QueueResource(Resource):

    qid = fields.CharField(attribute='qid')
    queue = fields.CharField(attribute='queue')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'queue'
        object_class = DitcObject
        authorization = Authorization()

    def _client(self):
        return RedisTool().get_redis()

    def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
        kwargs = {}

        if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
            kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.qid
        else:
            kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.qid

        return kwargs

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        queues = filter(lambda item:re.match(r'%s_update_plan\..+\..+' % PRO_FLAG, item), self._client().keys())
        results = []

        for result in queues:
            new_obj = DitcObject(initial={'queue': list(self._client().smembers(result))})
            new_obj.qid = result
            results.append(new_obj)

        return results

    def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        qid = bundle.request.GET.get('qid')
        if qid:
            return [obj for obj in self.get_object_list(bundle.request) if obj.qid == qid]
        return self.get_object_list(bundle.request)

    def obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        queue = self._client().smembers(kwargs['pk'])

        return DitcObject(initial={'queue': list(queue), 'qid': kwargs['pk']})

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)
        print kwargs
        return bundle
```

and this is my error return

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 09:20:35 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Content-Type: application/json

{"error": ""}
```

thanks all!

Comment: Please provide all relevant code.

Comment: i provide the whole code now

Comment: Do you see any useful information in your development server log?

Comment: Can you show the POST request you are submitting?

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance that you're `POST`-ing JSON data, and you've forgotten to surround the keys of your JSON data with double-quotes `"`.

That's one thing I faced right off the block when starting with TastyPie.

Comment: This answer just solved a very frustrating problem for me.  Thanks!